# using index to select range with repeated matches

Tags: excel

I have a set of data looks like below:

```
col_1 col_2
    a     9
    a     6
    b     4
    b     2
    c     1
```

I need to refer to the rows, which col_1 is "a" (then I will apply other function to the range such as `countifs`). I tried the formula below, which only pick up the first row because match only return the first matchable results. Is there a way to get what I need, please?

```
index(col_1, match("a", col_1, 0))
```

Comment: What do you actually need? Excel cannot display more than one cell in a single cell, so a range (e.g. B2:B3) cannot be displayed in a cell (e.g. C2). Do you need to sum the values of col_2 (i.e. 15)?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, I will apply other function to the range such as count and so on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` as array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(col_1="a",col_2)
```

to return the cells from col_2 that correspond to the values in col_1 that match `a`.

That said, I would say that the solution might be simpler depending on what you are trying to achieve because sometimes, there are functions already defined to do certain operations on ranges, such as `COUNTIF`/`COUNTIFS` would allow you to count the `a`s without the need to get a range matching something specific first (instead of going `=COUNT(IF(col_1="a",col_2))`).